# Activator.CreateInstance of Type returned from TypeBuilder.CreateType throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, multithreading, reflection.emit

I want to create types at Runtime and instantiate it via Activator.CreateInstance. I am using Refletion.Emit to do it and everithing works fine when the method that creates and instantiates the type runs in a single thread. Hoever, when I try to run the same method in more than one thread an ArgumentException is thrown.

The code is similar to:

```
class TypeBuilder
  public IMyType Build() {
    Type type = GetDynamicType("MyDynamicType");
    IMyType myType = (IMyType) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    return myType;
  }

  Type GetDynamicType(string typeName) {
    // define the module builder...
    ModuleBuilder module = ...
    Type type = module.GetType(typeName);
    if (type == null) {
      type = MakeDynamicType(typeName);
    }
    retyrn type;
  }

  Type MakeDynamicType(string typeName) {
     lock(lock_) { // lock_ is a static variable
        // ensure that the type was not already created by another thread.
        Type type =
           module
            .GetType(typeName);
        if (type != null) {
          return type;
        }
       // define the type builder...
       TypeBuilder builder = ...

       // define the type body...

       return type.CreateType();
     }
  }
}
```

Some observations:

- The exception is thrown only when more that one thread try to create the type.
- The first time the method is called and a exception is throw the returned type derives from TypeBuilder and not from RunTimeType, but the second time the method is called the type derives from RunTimeType.

Update 1:

The exception message is : "Type must be a type provided by the runtime."

Update 2:

The full source is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/nohros/must/blob/master/src/base/common/data/mappers/DataReaderMapperBuilder.cs)

Comment: What's the actual exception message? Are there any inner exceptions? Please paste those. Also, since this is multi-threaded, can you guarantee that you created the Type first before the other thread attempted to instantiate?

Comment: Yes, I check the type for existence before instantiate it.

Comment: Please post your complete code, not the "similar to" above, can you also include and example of how you might call the `TypeBuilder` as well. Thanks.

Comment: The code is too big to be posted. I have added a link to the file containing the full code.

Comment: _"The code is too big to be posted"_ -- nobody wants _the_ code. Please provide [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe a late answer, but in any way.

In your code, `GetDynamicType` is not thread safe, there are two race conditions which aren't handled. The more interesting of them is as follows:

One thread defines a new type with `ModuleBuilder.DefineType(...)`. It gets `TypeBuilder` object which it then uses to build the type.

At the same time, the other thread calls `ModuleBuilder.GetType(...)` and gets the `Type` object it looks for... at least it thinks so. It assumes it got the `RuntimeType`, but actually, it gets the `TypeBuilder` being built by the first thread.

Only when the first thread calls `TypeBuilder.CreateType()`, the `TypeBuilder` is replaced with the corresponding `RuntimeType` in the `ModuleBuilder`.

And so you end up with trying to `Activator.CreateInstance` of a `TypeBuilder`, which throws the "Type must be a type provided by the runtime" exception.

I would suggest rewriting `GetDynamicType` function and use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>` with `MakeDynamicType` as value factory:

```
  private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> _dynamicTypesByName = 
      new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>();

  Type GetDynamicType(string typeName) {
    // define the module builder...
    ModuleBuilder module = ...
    return _dynamicTypesByName.GetOrAdd(typeName, MakeDynamicType);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was the race condition and I solved it by using a lock() inside the GetDynamicType before the GetType.